# Theme.Holo with Dark Action Bar

Tags: android

I am making a daydream application and I want the settings activity to follow the same interface as the standard settings. For right now I want to make the app use the Holo theme but have a dark action bar like you can get with the Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme. I've googled around and have not found anything similar, and I tried looking through the android source code to find out how they do it for the Settings page, but it is too big for me to handle and I cannot find the styling system.

I've got my styles set up but I cannot find the correct value to use for actionbar style. I do not have interest in adding more libraries like actionbar sherlock.

NOTE: Dark Action Bar =/= Holo actionbar. 
My app only works with 4.2 and up so the Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme should exist.

For reference, I want my app to have this theme:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The settings app uses the `Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid` for its `actionBarStyle`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/res/values/themes.xml#L62). As in:

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I spent hours looking for this and never even found a mention of it. Hopefully it helps otehrs too.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for API 8? It requires API 14.